# PHP - Convert JSON string to HTML Select Option

Tags: php, json

I am trying to convert a JSON string to html `<select>` options, but need to achieve all this in PHP without JS or jQuery. Appreciate any help.

Some background: the JSON result contains 2 columns, `timestamp` and `chapter_name`, which is used for a video to jump to the location of `x` seconds via a select dropdown where the user can choose which chapter he wants to jump to.

```
$json_str = '{"timestamp":"0","chapter_name":"Introduction"},{"timestamp":"20","chapter_name":"Chapter 1"},{"timestamp":"40","chapter_name":"Chapter 2"},{"timestamp":"100","chapter_name":"Chapter 3"}';

$timestamps_arr = json_decode($json_str, true);
$timestamps_output = "
    <label for=\"sel_timestamps\">Jump to: </label>
    <select id=\"sel_timestamps\" name=\"sel_timestamps\" onchange=\"VidTimeJump()\">";

foreach($timestamps_arr as $timestamp){
    echo '<option value="'.$timestamp['timestamp'].'">'.$timestamp['chapter_name'].'</option>';
}

$timestamps_output .= "
    </select>";
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the code you have.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Don't `echo` out your options, concatenate them using `$timestamps_output .= ...`. Then `echo $timestamps_output;`

Comment: And this is why you don't code late at night... thanks guys, appreciate it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you're using is invalid. To make your code work you should also append your `<option>`s (`$timestamps_output .= ...`) instead of `echo`ing them right away. You'll end up with a string `$timestamps_output` that contains your `<label>` and `<select>` including your options.

```
$json_str = '[{"timestamp":"0","chapter_name":"Introduction"},{"timestamp":"20","chapter_name":"Chapter 1"},{"timestamp":"40","chapter_name":"Chapter 2"},{"timestamp":"100","chapter_name":"Chapter 3"}]';

$timestamps_arr = json_decode($json_str, true);
$timestamps_output = "
    <label for=\"sel_timestamps\">Jump to: </label>
    <select id=\"sel_timestamps\" name=\"sel_timestamps\" onchange=\"VidTimeJump()\">";

foreach($timestamps_arr as $timestamp){
    $timestamps_output .= '<option value="'.$timestamp['timestamp'].'">'.$timestamp['chapter_name'].'</option>';
}

$timestamps_output .= "
    </select>";
```

Use `echo $timestamps_output;` to output

```
<label for="sel_timestamps">Jump to: </label>
<select id="sel_timestamps" name="sel_timestamps" onchange="VidTimeJump()"><option value="0">Introduction</option><option value="20">Chapter 1</option><option value="40">Chapter 2</option><option value="100">Chapter 3</option>
</select>
```